# Magento 2 CSS inlining error in Order Success mail

Tags: magento2, order-email

I am working on **Magento ver. 2.1.10**.

After the Order is successfully placed, the customer is getting a mail regarding the successful order in which a warning error appears:

**CSS inlining error: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Undefined namespace prefix in public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 269** .

What I have **already checked** :

> Put this in the require-dev part of composer.json:
>   "pelago/emogrifier": "1.0.0 as 0.1.1"

But still issue persists.

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the colon (:) in the classes :last-* :nth- if you remove the colon from the CSS then the issue should go away, i would recommend looking at finding an alternative solution to targeting the second element